# MySQL crashed, data missing

Tags: mysql, crash

My server recently had a power outage. My MySQL tables which are in InnoDB format are all corrupted.  I tried innodb_force_recovery, it didn't work, there were missing tables, and one database was even completely empty.  I tried copying individual database folders for each database from the data folder of old backups, and even copied the entire data folder, and nothing is working!

Comment: Make sure that you restore configuration files (and even logs, although I don't think logs are relevant but it wouldn't hurt).

Comment: Do you have backup of the databases? If yes then you can restore from them; else I am afraid.